# How to use dual monitors on a system with 2 computers?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors set up to work with extended screens on Windows 7.

Now I've hooked a computer to one of these monitors (monitor 1) with Ubuntu.

When I change the input source on monitor 1. I see Ubuntu in it, but I still get extended screen for Windows 7, hampering its usability.

Is there a way to force the screens to work as individual monitors, meaning that monitor 1 only has Ubuntu, and 2 only has Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows PC still sees second monitor as active when you switch inputs to display Ubuntu, that's why. But if you use KVM switch to commutate second monitor to either one of two inputs, then Windows should see it like that monitor was turned off (depends on KVM model though). Default OS behavior in this situation is to fall back to single monitor view.